# 2d vector class for PlayN?

Tags: java, eclipse, playn

I see the jbox2d Vec2 class in the repository:

http://code.google.com/p/playn/source/browse/gwtbox2d/src/org/jbox2d/common/Vec2.java

How do I make the **PlayN port of JBox2D package** accessible to my code? I'm using Eclipse but my project does not appear to be aware of the package.

---

**Update:**

Following the example [here](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/core/pom.xml), I've added playn-jbox2d as a dependency in my core/pom.xml file. However, when I load my project I get the following error:

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.googlecode.playn:playn-jbox2d:jar:1.1.1:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact
>   com.googlecode.playn:playn-jbox2d:pom:1.1.1 from/to central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/playn/playn-jbox2d/1.1.1/playn-jbox2d-1.1.1.pom.
>   Error code 416, Requested Range Not
>   Satisfiable   pom.xml /myproject-core line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

Comment: Did you put the library into the class path (Eclipse: build path)?

Comment: @Thomas I followed the directions for setting up PlayN but beyond that I'm still pretty helpless. This is my first Java/Eclipse project so I'm learning as go. I've poked around the Eclipse menus but wasn't able to figure out how to enable this package.

Comment: Figured this out at last. Still to soon for me to add my answer below, so I've posted it on my website in the meantime: http://klenwell.com/is/Pastebin20120317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of a goose chase, I figured out how to enable this. Following the example [here](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/core/pom.xml), I manually added **playn-jbox2d** as a dependency in my `core/pom.xml` file. Here is what that section of my `pom.xml` file now looks like:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
      <artifactId>playn-core</artifactId>
      <version>${playn.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
      <artifactId>playn-jbox2d</artifactId>
      <version>${playn.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Then in Eclipse:

Right-click **core** directory in Package Explorer window > Maven > Update Dependencies

Thanks to all who offered assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add JBox2D library to your workspace. Follow [Basic guide for importing and building JBox2D](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/wiki/QuickStart). There are instructions for eclipse as well. Or you can [download](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/downloads/list) JBox2D jars and add them to eclipse. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) how to add jars to your workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've upvoted as this points me in the right direction but doesn't really answer my question. I hate to seem feeble, but I'm not familiar with potential benefits/complications of each approach and whether PlayN has a specific recommended method. In any event, it's helped me clarify my question.

Comment: @klenwell, did you try to follow [Getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted)?

Comment: Yes. Apparently you need to specify playn-jbox2d as a dependency. Following the example here http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/core/pom.xml?#16, I've added it to my pom.xml file. Now I'm getting an ArtifactDescriptorException for which I guess I'll open a new question.